# No se muestra el resultado de ajax en un input type="text ASP.NET MVC!

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net, mvc

El problema es el siguiente: Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con ASP.NET MVC 5... y me esta sucediendo un error extrañísimo (perdonen mi desconocimiento si no es tan extraño). El asunto es que, al cargar una pagína para Agregar un nuevo registro, se muestran todos los controles correctamente. Y con Ajax, ejecuto un método en el Servidor que me retorna el valor del cambio de una moneda (en tiempo real) para el campo "Cambio". Los parámetros son los valores de otros dos campos: 'DataBanca' y 'Divisa'. Siempre que sea, un nuevo registro, el control se actualiza perfectamente y muestra el resultado. Además, esto lo compruebo, mostrando el valor devuelto en la consola.

Sin embargo, si lo hago al Mofificar un registro, no ocurre lo mismo. El valor devuelto no se muestra en el input tipo texto (TextboxFor... aunque da igual error con EditorFor) y raramente, no sé por qué; se muestra todo el contenido HTML en el input. Y además, en la consola también se muestra todo ese código html inmenso. En realidad son mas campos, pero para no buscarme problemas, solo les detallo el que me da error. ¿Qué creen Uds que pueda estar pasando ó qué estoy haciendo mal? Les detallo mejor el escenario:

**Controlador**

```
public JsonResult Cambio(DateTime data, string divisa)
    {
        using (var dbDRC = new conDRC())
        {
            var model = dbDRC.GetCambi(data, "USD").FirstOrDefault();

            string valore = "";

            if (model != null)
                valore = model.VALORE;

            return Json(valore, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

**Html**

```
    <div class="side-right">
         <label>Data Banca: </label>
         @Html.EditorFor(m => m.DataBanca, new { htmlAttributes = new { @required = "required" } })
    </div>
    
    <div class="side-left">
         <label>Divisa Titolo: </label>
         <input type="text" id="Id_DivisaTitolo" , name="Id_DivisaTitolo" value="@ViewBag.DivisaTitolo" readonly class="form-control" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="side-left">
         <label>Cambio: </label>
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Cambio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Cambio", @readonly = "readonly", @required = "required" } })
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function GetCambio() {
     var dataBanca = $("#DataBanca").val();
     var divisa = $("#Id_DivisaTitolo").val();

    if (dataBanca.length != 0 & divisa.length != 0) {
        if (divisa == "EUR") {
            $("#Cambio").val(1);
        } else {
            var url = "@Url.Action("Cambio", "Periodo")";
            var data = { data: dataBanca, divisa: divisa };

            $.get(url, data).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#Cambio").val(data);
            });
        }
    } else {
        $("#Cambio").val("");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#DataBanca").change(function () {
        GetCambio();
    });
});
```

La función GetCambio es llamada, cuando el control 'DataBanca' cambia de valor. Para el caso de la divisa, en este caso, es un valor fijo que viene desde el Controlador.

El método en el Controlador, lo he cambiado a [HttpPost] y sigue ocurriendo lo mismo. ¿Por qué se ejecuta sin problemas si es un nuevo registro y de manera diversa para una edición? Muchas Gracias a todos por la ayuda y comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Disculpen amigos, pero me olvidé de publicar las imágenes...

[image: Esto ocurre cuando es un nuevo registro. Vean que se muestra el valor del cambio, sin problemas]

[image: Y esto ocurre cuando es una modificación. Vean que se muestra el valor contenido html]